# Converting list into a grouped list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
['Ben\n', '5 0 0 5 -5 \n', 'Moose\n', '5 5 0 3 0 0 \n', ...]
```

that carries on like that for a long time.  I need to make this list into a list of tuples like this:

```
[('Ben', '5 0 0 5 -5'), ('Moose', '5 5 0 3 0 0'), ...] and so on.
```

I feel like this should be easy.
I've already opened the text file and split it into a list by line this way:

```
e = open("bookratings.txt", "r")
elines = e.readlines()
```

But I don't know where to go from here?

Comment: Shortening the example would make the question and answers much more readable.

Answer (score 5):

looks like each person has associated data at its very next line, so that makes two lines of data per person.
you can `zip` it.

```
lst = list(zip(*[iter(lst)]*2))
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return an error?  The "'lst' referenced before assignment."

Comment: @user2180683 `lst` would be both the original and the resulting list.

Comment: For the uninformed there is a lot of magic here.  Care to add an explanation?

Comment: Also, OP was looking for a solution that strips newlines.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski `[iter(lst)]*2` creates a two-element-list with a single iterator as both the elements. As it’s the exact same, identical iterator, consuming items on the first list item will also consume those on the second. So when running `zip` which pairs elements from two (or more) iterators, it will keep consuming two items from the iterator (once for each list item) and group them like that. The `*list` inside will turn the list into separate arguments of the `zip` function; so everything works out.

Comment: @poke:  I was suggesting you edit your answer.  I understand it just fine, although there was a time when it would have confused me.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski If it was my answer, I’d edit it, but I rather want to leave thkang the chance to do it :)

Comment: @poke:  Whoops.  Sorry.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Although somewhat magical to those not familiar with iterators, `zip(*[iter(inputlist)*n])` is a fairly standard trick to create a 2-wise grouper. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  Right.  But we're talking about an OP who opens files without using `with` and who reflexively uses `readlines` on a file.  So I thought a little explanation was needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
>>> li=['Ben\n', '5 0 0 5 -5 \n', 'Moose\n', '5 5 0 3 0 0 \n']
>>> zip(*[(e.strip() for e in li)]*2)
[('Ben', '5 0 0 5 -5'), ('Moose', '5 5 0 3 0 0')]
```

The `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` part is based on from the Python documents on [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for `idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups`.

I added the generator inside to strip the carriage returns. Once the generator expression is there, the `iter` is no longer needed. (Thanks @StevenRumbalski)

Of course, you mentioned that you have a file like object like so:

```
Ben
5 0 0 0 -5
Moose
5 5 0 3 0 0
...
```

If so, here is an alternative where you do not have to read the entire file in:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/lines.txt','r') as f:
...    it=iter(f)
...    li=[(i.strip(),it.next().strip()) for i in it]
... 
>>> li
[('Ben', '5 0 0 0 -5'), ('Moose', '5 5 0 3 0 0')]
```

Comment: No need for `iter`:  `zip(*[(e.strip() for e in li)]*2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
>>a = ['Ben\n', '5 0 0 5 -5 \n', 'Moose\n', '5 5 0 3 0 0 \n']

>>b = ''.join(a).split('\n')
```

Now

```
>> c = [(b[i],b[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(b)-1,2)]
```

should give you the result

```
[('Ben', '5 0 0 5 -5 '), ('Moose', '5 5 0 3 0 0 ')]
```